# Is is good idea to store long term data in Zip format?

Tags: backup, file-transfer, zip, storage

**Situation**

I have huge amount (around 1 TB) of mixed data (photos, documents, pdfs and other kind of file formats). All data is arranged in *many* folders. As my laptop drive is keep filling , I have to move this data to some kind of long term storage. I have decided to transfer this data to one [regular](https://www.wdc.com/products/portable-storage/my-passport.html) external hard drive as well as one [NAS device](https://www.wdc.com/products/personal-cloud-storage/my-cloud.html).

**Question**

Is it good idea to zip everything and transfer to these devices ? I am planning to use 7Zip for this process. It might save some space also can [increase](https://superuser.com/questions/125141/is-there-a-way-to-transfer-thousand-of-small-files-faster-on-windows-7) transfer rate. Further can also save any unexpected deletion of files by any antivirus.

**Further Problem**

Last time I was transferring such huge data, there were some files which I could not transfer due to some error or corruption. If something like this happens for zipped archive, then I am screwed.

Suggestion about any other better way to storing and transferring such big data is also welcome.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser. Your question is mostly answered by matter of opinion. Although there is some science involved, asking of something is a good idea basically is asking for opinions. This means the question is off-topic for SuperUser, as we're not a forum. That said, Although the Zip format is not going to degrade, the storage medium will. If any part of the zip file becomes damaged, everything is lost.

Comment: @LPChip, ok thank you. Should I delete this question then ?

Comment: You answered your own question: "If something like this happens for zipped archive, then I am screwed". Disks are cheap now - if your backup disk fills up, then buy another one, don't use compression, encryption, or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

A few points come to mind:-

- Space saving: many files, especially multimedia, are already in a compressed format, and little space will be gained by trying to compress further (indeed, I have seen multimedia files in a ZIP archive that are larger than the original, though the ZIP program should recognise that this will happen and store without trying to apply further compression).
- Access times: a large archive can take a long time to access and update.
- Access security: using a ZIP password gives cheap and cheerful protection to the archive, which is very portable without requiring extra security software on the target machine, though it will not resist a determined effort to break it.
- Data security: a data error in a filing system may lose a few files residing in the faulty sector, but can lose all the files in a ZIP archive.
- Archive size: if you store a lot of large files in a ZIP archive, the archive size may become unmanageable; I would avoid any archives over 20GB.

You are very wise to back up in two places. As for what you back up, I suggest you do some tests as to what files give worthwhile compression: in my experience text files and document (`.txt`, `.log`, `.doc`, .`docx`, etc) files can save up to 90%, *uncompressed* multimedia files (`.wav`, `.bmp`, etc) around 50%, but compressed files (`.mp*`, `.zip`, some `.pdf`, installation files, etc) will give at most 2%, if that.

If you do zip your files, you may want to consider one file per archive. This will not give as good compression as multiple file archives, but will give reasonable data security.

For the record, I have used `7zip` for years and find it excellent, and it has a command-line interface which is useful for batch operations.

Comment: I wonder about **data security**: if I were to choose a reasonable block-size (so a non-solid archive) - wouldn't that possible even improve data security?blob:https://superuser.com/0e93ece1-b5b4-48f8-bacd-a2deb758acf1would that still hurt data security? Also, with some archive formats (AFAIK), you can deliberately sacrifice the archive size by adding redundancy information - this would help, too, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely and opinion based Q/A but, I would recommend software like WinRAR that can create a recovery record.  Archives are great for a snapshot in time, ease of management, and tracking **but large archives are susceptible to corruption.**

**You can hash the files, but this will not allow recovery; it will simply tell you the file(s) is not the original anymore.  Archives with a recovery record can actually heal themselves.**

Space savings for a large size consumer drive usually means lots of compressed data meaning you space savings will be very small so largest gain is ease of management and recovery; but you have to us an archive method that can actually do that.  I am unaware of a long standing format other than WinRAR.

As for the device, a running NAS is much better than a cold stored HDD because a NAS can tell you if a drive is bad so you can take care of the problem where a cold stored HDD may be go from "good" to "bad" and you don't even know it.  **Cloud is probably your best option if your not tech savy.**  If you are tech savy, get a used LTO3/4 drive and tapes with a controller card.  A prebuilt NAS can be a more expensive option after you calc in the upfront hardware and power cost over time.